# Regular Expression HTML tags

Tags: html, regex

I'd like to know whether it exists a way to put the following HTML tags in a regex. What I want is a regex that can match all the start tags with their corresponding closing tags.
E.g.,

```
<div id="bla">
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
    <span>
        <span></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

There might be more tags inside.
I had thought of something like this: `^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$/`, but it wont work.
Sorry if this question doesnt belong to this section.
Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use a regular expression for this purpose. CSS selectors and XPath would both be better for the job.

Comment: This question gets asked all the time with the same answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions can parse [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

**X**HTML is a [context free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) which cannot be parsed by a regular expression.  An example of a context free language is a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> which would match `ab`, `aabb`, `aaabbb` or any other string of `a`s followed by an equal number of `b`s.  This is easily shown not to be regular using the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

HTML is ideally a context free language too, however it rarely is.  HTML parsers can accept all manner of improperly formatted text such as `<b>foo<i>bar</b></i>` and try to make something of it.

When trying to parse html, use an html parser that is designed for processing the DOM rather than rolling one of your own.  Especially with regular expressions.  You *will* do it wrong because it *cannot* be done right, and then you will have [two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/40980).

Answer (score 0):

May you also be need not regexp approach but try to parse/query html page using tools like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)?

This way you'll get needed part of page's code or content without messing with regexp and (which is good) you'll be able to search for or get attributes values.